# How wil get Context Path in log4j property files?

Tags: log4j, contextpath

How wil get Context Path in log4j property files? Ex: My log file name would be contextpath.log.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a different appender for each context path. And Implement each context in a different Controller class.

for example

```
<appender name="FILE-1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">    
    <param name="File" value="contextpath1.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d::[%t]::%-5p::%c::%x - %m%n" />
    </layout>       
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">    
    <param name="File" value="contextpath2.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d::[%t]::%-5p::%c::%x - %m%n" />
    </layout>       
</appender>
<logger name="com.mycompany.apackage.Context1Class">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-1"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.mycompany.apackage.Context2Class">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-2"/>
</logger>
```